# How to call component method from app event in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How do we update component data, inside a app event? this.matches = x gets ignored

```
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    matches; // How to refresh this??

    constructor() {
        app.on(app.resumeEvent, (args: app.ApplicationEventData) => {

            // how to change matches here??
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Youe question is not very much clear? What do you want to update in resumeEvent? How do you get the initial value of matches? you can use the same method in resumeEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run your code inside NgZone as resume event will be triggered outside Angular's context.

```
constructor(ngZone: NgZone) {
    app.on(app.resumeEvent, (args: app.ApplicationEventData) => {
         ngZone.run(() => {
            // Update here
         });
    });
}
```